# How to get past CORS with Express JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, cors

After deploying my site it stopped functioning due to CORS errors.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend-heroku.herokuapp.com/posts' from origin 'https://website1231.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

---

I thought I could fix it by adding

```
res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", *)
```

to all the requests, but that didn't work.

---

Then I tried downloading the [CORS middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and using that

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express ()

const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

but that doesn't work either.

So I tried adding options like this:

```
let corsOptions = {
  origin: true
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

still didn't work

Then lastly in the routes for all the requests like:

```
app.get("/posts", cors(), (request, response) => {
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  let posts = [];
  db.collection("posts")
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        posts.push(doc.data());
      });
      response.send(posts);
    });
  console.log("posts=", posts);
});
```

still didn't work.

---

Then I tried a bunch of code from links on this website:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ["*"]);
  res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  next();
});
```

Doesnt work

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested, Content-Type, Accept Authorization"
  )
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE"
    )
    return res.status(200).json({})
  }
  next()
})
```

Doesn't work

---

Does anybody know how to fix this? I feel like I've exhausted all my options. Are there security options I have to select in the settings of Heroku or Firebase? Is my code just wrong?

---

Here's the entirety of the code as I deployed it, when I finally got CORS working through Firebase (frontend) and Localhost (backend) and thought it would work between Firebase and Heroku too.

**index.js**

```
//========DEPENDENCIES==========
const express = require("express");
const { initializeApp, cert } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
const { getStorage } = require("firebase-admin/storage");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const cors = require("cors");
const busboy = require("busboy");
let path = require("path");
let os = require("os");
let fs = require("fs");
let fields = {};
let fileData = {};

//========EXPRESS JS==========

const app = express();


app.use(cors())

//========FIREBASE==========

const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
const { useAttrs } = require("vue");

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: "website-1233f.appspot.com",
});

const db = getFirestore();
const bucket = getStorage().bucket();

//========END POINTS========

app.get("/posts", (request, response) => {
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  let posts = [];
  db.collection("posts")
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        posts.push(doc.data());
      });
      response.send(posts);
    });
  console.log("posts=", posts);
});

app.post("/createPost", (request, response) => {
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  let token_id = uuidv4();

  const bb = busboy({ headers: request.headers });

  bb.on("file", (name, file, info) => {
    const { filename, encoding, mimeType } = info;
    let filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    fileData = { filepath, mimeType };
    console.log(
      `File [${name}]: filename: %j, encoding: %j, mimeType: %j`,
      filename,
      encoding,
      mimeType
    );
    file
      .on("data", (data) => {
        console.log(`File [${name}] got ${data.length} bytes`);
      })
      .on("close", () => {
        console.log(`File [${name}] done`);
      });
  });

  bb.on("field", (name, val, info) => {
    console.log(`Field [${name}]: value: %j`, val);
    fields[name] = val;
  });

  bb.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Done parsing form!");
    bucket.upload(
      fileData.filepath,
      {
        uploadType: "media",
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: fileData.mimeType,
            firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: token_id,
          },
        },
      },
      (err, uploadedFile) => {
        if (!err) {
          createDocument(uploadedFile);
        }
      }
    );
    // response.writeHead(303, { Connection: "close", Location: "/" });
    function createDocument(uploadedFile) {
      db.collection("posts")
        .doc(fields.id)
        .set({
          id: fields.id,
          caption: fields.caption,
          location: fields.location,
          date: parseInt(fields.date),
          imgUrl: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucket.name}/o/${uploadedFile.name}?alt=media&token=${token_id}`,
          name: fields.name,
        })
        .then((req, res) => {
          response.send("Post created");
        });
    }
  });
  request.pipe(bb);
});

app.delete("/deletePost/:id", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  db.collection("posts").doc(req.params.id).delete();
  res.send({ result: `Deleted post with id: ${req.params.id}` });
});

//========LOCALHOST LISTEN==========
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You have to set up your server so that it allows HTTP requests either from your specific application domain, or else from *all* domains. Or, alternatively, you can use a proxy on your application server to make the requests for you and return the results to the clients.

Comment: @Pointy  `app.use(cors())` typically does exactly that: it allows CORS from any origin ... And for your suggestion of a proxy: this would need to be reachable under `https://website1231.web.app` As I understand the question, the frontend is hosted on Firebase Hosting, so I suppose it's not that easy to run a proxy service there ...

Comment: The `cors` middleware typically works quite well and when called without any options, it allows pretty much everything in the context of CORS. So if that doesn't work for you, there may be something wrong with your deployment. Have you made sure, you really deployed the latest version of your service?

Comment: Well `app.use(cors())` is on *your* server, right? The CORS headers need to be set on the Heroku side, as that is the target of your cross-domain request.

Comment: @Pointy the shown `index.js` (ie the backend) probably is deployed to heroku as well (but quite obvious not in that exact version)

Comment: @derpirscher maybe, maybe not; we don't know for sure because the OP doesn't explicitly say. All we know is that it's not working, so if it is deployed to Heroku there's something wrong with how that was done.

Comment: @Pointy The code posted, the index.js, is exactly what is hosted to Heroku right now and being used as a backend.

Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Could you post your backend url?

Comment: @EricAndre well first thing to do is use your browser's Network developer tool to examine the request and response headers on the failed cross-origin request. If it's failing, then you'll see that there are either no CORS headers, or that they're incorrect.

Comment: I figured it out. This line of code:

`const { useAttrs } = require("vue")`

was crashing the backend. IDK why the dev console was telling me it was a CORS error. I guess because since the backend crashed it wasn't able to send the appropriate headers back. Wasted 2 days on this lol.